# What does this expression mean in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.scroll').selectRow({
        delButtonSelect: '#' + deleteButtonID,
        editButtonSelect: '#' + editButtonID
    })
        .createCheckboxRange({
            chkSelected: Common.highlightParentRows
        })
        .showExtraInfo('.LargeField_link', '.extra_info', 800);
    setBoxSizes(40);

});
```

The expression above is a part of a web application that uses jquery. I am tyring to understand what it does. I went thru the w3schools tutorial on jquery, but I couldn't figure out the expression above.

Any pointers on what I should search in google to understand the expression above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be some kind of a jQuery plugin. Without more information we cannot say what it is doing.

Comment: Well knowing that its a plugin itself is helpful. Now I can narrow my search, thank you :)

Comment: [Also be careful with the tings you see on W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @developer747. It's probably "home-made" plugin, see my answer

Comment: @developer747, This really isn't an adequate question for SO, and I was about to vote to close it with barely a glance like I do with every other question like this, but I really, really like your attitude (mostly your comment!), so I'll instead wish you luck in finding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jQuery core code, jQuery base code doesn't have `selectRow` \ `createCheckboxRange` \ `showExtraInfo` functions...

So it's probably a plugin of jQuery. So we can't know what it does.

By the way, [searching](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=selectRow%20%20createCheckboxRange%20%20jquery%20plugin&ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&safe=active&btnG=Search) those functions on Google returned pretty much this question only...
So it's probably a "home-made" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

selectRow(), createCheckboxRange(), and showExtraInfo() aren't stock jQuery functions (not that I know about anyway), so must be part of a plugin or custom functions defined somewhere else in the source.

Take a look at the other scripts included on the page and see if you can find the code that creates that function.

If it's been don't right, comments should either have, or provide a link for, some documentation that will walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all the objects that are classed as "scroll" and makes active the correct delete and edit buttons.

It looks like it is using the [jQuery Field Plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/field/field.plugin.htm) to allow multi-selection of some checkboxes.

Then it shows an element that presumably contains additional info.

Without more of the code, it's pretty difficult to be more specific.